# Protecting ftpclient login credentials

Tags: security, ftp, passwords

My Java app for Windows requires uploading results to a server using an ftp client. Currently, I have the port, sever URL, username and password in an ini file that the app installer places on the users computer. I'm concerned that a user can easily open the ini file and see these credentials and thus be able to log in to my account on the server. I'm considering encryption of the username & password. Or, just ask the user to provide his/her own credentials, perhaps using Google or other free outgoing service? Are there better ways of handling this?

Comment: No matter what you do for protecting the credentials, FTP is a plaintext protocol, therefore you just have to use Wireshark to see which credentials are used. Therefore DO NOT USE FTP! And second: DO NOT USE  A COMMON USER ACCOUNT.

Comment: Yup agree with @Robert , go for SFTP

Answer (score 0):

With SFTP, a connection can be authenticated using a couple different techniques one of them involves using Public / Private Key Pair.
With key-based authentication, you will need to generate a SSH private key and public key beforehand. If you want to connect to a partner's SFTP server, you would then send your SSH public key to them so they can load onto their server and associate with your account. Then, once you've connected to their SFTP server, your client software will transmit your public key to the server for authentication. If the keys match, along with any username/password supplied, the authentication will succeed.

Comment: But users still can extract the private key from the app and use it for login. I the end it does not matter if you use username+password or a username+private key. Just do not use accounts that are not user specific.

Comment: Yeah .. though you have a Java Key Store where you may keep the private key , but then the app will need the KeyStore password , which however can be generated based on some binding from the machine where the App is running besides we need to control the access to the files and folder through necessary permissions at the OS level.

Comment: Well, indeed, there's no way to allow any kind of automatic authentication that 1) does not need any external service (like Kerberos, OAuth, Google, etc) 2) and yet does not allow exposing the credentials.

Comment: So, just to clarify, or reveal my misunderstanding as the case may be, the best thing to do is require each user to enter his/her personal username/password. Is that correct? And if I do that, is there any need to use SFTP?

Answer (score 0):

Finally got back to this issue, and here's what I've learned.

First, I've decided to provide FTP access on my hosting server with a "home" directory so the user can't access site data other than his own. I will provide the username and password to the user. Second, the username will be stored in the Windows app database. Third, **neither the password or a SaltHash of that password will be stored in the database**. Thus the user must type in the password on each FTP upload.

The reason for not using SaltHash because is it's pointless. I.e., if I did go to the trouble of creating and storing a SaltHash, the user would **still have to type in a password**. That entered password could be salt hashed and compared with the stored SaltHash to be sure it's valid but that's no better than getting an acceptance or rejection from the server.

Or, what am I missing?